# Google oAuth 2.0 (JWT token request) for Service Application

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, jwt

I'm trying to implement Google oAuth 2 for service accounts described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount on UnityScript (or C# - that doesn't matter because they both use the same Mono .NET classes).

I've found similar topic here: [Is there a JSON Web Token (JWT) example in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055158/is-there-a-json-)
web-token-jwt-example-in-c but I still don't have a success.

Fist of all, I have generated header and claimset (that are just like in google documentation)

```js
var header: String = GetJWTHeader();
var claimset: String = GetJWTClaimSet();
```

The result is (separated with new lines for clarity):

> {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
>
> {"iss":"425466719070-1dg2rebp0a8fn9l02k9ntr6u5o4a8lp2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>
> "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
>
> "aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
>
> "exp":1340222315,
>
> "iat":1340218715}

Base-64 encoding methods:

```js
public static function Base64Encode(b: byte[]): String {
    var s: String = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
    s = s.Replace("+", "-");
    s = s.Replace("/", "_");
    s = s.Split("="[0])[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
    return s;
}

public static function Base64Encode(s: String): String {    
    return Base64Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
}
```

Then I'm making a signature.

```js
var to_sign: byte[] = 
     Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Base64Encode(header) + "." + Base64Encode(claimset));
var cert: X509Certificate2 = 
     new X509Certificate2(google_pvt_key.ToArray(), "notasecret");
var rsa: RSACryptoServiceProvider = cert.PrivateKey;
var sgn: String = Base64Encode(rsa.SignData(to_sign, "SHA256"));

var jwt: String = Base64Encode(header) + "." + Base64Encode(claimset) + 
                     "." + sgn;
```

And then forming the request:

```js
var url: String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
var form: WWWForm = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("grant_type", "assertion");
form.AddField("assertion_type", "http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer");
form.AddField("assertion", jwt);
var headers: Hashtable = form.headers;
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var www: WWW = new WWW(url, form.data, headers);
```

And all I get is "**Error 400: Bad request**".

The encoded data looks like (line breaks added for clarity):

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.
>
> eyJpc3MiOiI0MjU0NjY3MTkwNzAtMWRnMnJlYnAwYThmbjlsMDJrOW50cjZ1NW80YThscDIuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvcHJlZGljdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTM0MDIyMjMxNSwiaWF0IjoxMzQwMjE4NzE1fQ.
>
> lIFg7-Og_BcC5qpICLt7USwGIHUOz-vV4ADNq0AWhuRtsvFrbZn5mxk4n9r5qU66q4reTVVAtuW06DeGsdcBMNgEdIMvN6VuYQybs64p9mqrfECBYxO1FWHbUG-2On1IpowybEsRRUjZfp0jFuEY7SLE3XRaXan0k5zmejcvLQo

I've spent two days trying to figure out what is wrong but I can't see.

Also, I couldn't find any suitable documentation and examples.

I'm trying just to recieve a token.

1. Am I signing the bytes the right way?
2. What should "scope" parameter in claimset look like? I've tried "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.readonly" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction".
3. What "iss" parameter should be equal to? Client-id or e-mail address? (tried both)
4. What are the ways to find out my mistake?
5. Are there any C# libraries for Service Application (not for installed apps or client login)?

I'm getting crazy... It has to work, but it doesn't... :-/

Comment: I'm having a tough time too implementing service account authentication in c#! Can you confirm for me that you successfully used the grant_type and assertion_type fields as they are shown in your example? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was that in request code all slashes have to be backslashed

WRONG:

```
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
"aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
```

CORRECT:

```
"scope":"https:\\/\\/www.googleapis.com\\/auth\\/prediction",
"aud":"https:\\/\\/accounts.google.com\\/o\\/oauth2\\/token",
```

Comment: soulburner you are my hero! Thank you very much!I wish I could upvote 10 times :D

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.114).aspx) .Net library 
You can install it from NuGet.
See example in my post here (I used it to authenticate websockets server, but JWT handling is generic)

http://mydevtricks.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/xsocketsnet-authentication-with-jwt.html