# Validating JWT Asymmetrically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm trying to do a proof of concept validating a json web token asymmetrically in c#. I'm currently trying the Json Web Token Handler for Microsoft.NET library, but I'm struggling to get it to work. The documentation is limited, and most posts online are either issuing tokens or validating tokens symmetrically. I was able to *symmetrically* validate a token using the generic JWT library as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055158/is-there-a-json-web-token-jwt-example-in-c), but the solution provided there does not handle asymmetric validation, based on the way the decode function is written.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certpath, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
if (privateKey == null)
{
   throw new Exception("Not an RSA private key");
}
var cspBlob = privateKey.ExportCspBlob(true);
var pk = Convert.ToBase64String(cspBlob);

//This code also works instead of the above code, I believe
//var privateKey = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
   ValidAudience = "exampleAudience",
   ValidIssuer = "exampleIssuer",                    
   IssuerSigningToken = pk
};

//The token passed in here is a string version of the token
//I have tried both a JWTSecurityToken token and just a string version
ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = jwtHandler.ValidateToken(asymmetricToken, tokenValidationParameters);
if (claimsPrincipal != null)
{
    // Valid
    Console.Write("Valid!");
}
```

I'm getting a couple of errors, namely in the tokenValidationParameters section and the Validate token method. I'm just not sure how these functions work with respect to my scenario. What validation parameters do I need to set? Also, I see on the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.114).aspx) that there is an overloaded method that takes a token and validation parameters, but I'm getting a compilation error indicating that no version of this method takes 2 parameters.

Lastly, does anyone know if this code will actually work for asymmetric validation, or does the ValidateToken method on JWTHandler only work for symmetric validation?

Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question, and just wanted to share. I ended up using the JWT library I used for symmetric validation. I stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt/issues/27) and found that they branched the library and included code for asymmetric validation. The code for the implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/abatishchev/jwt/blob/rs256-1/JWT/JWT.cs).

The code I used to import my .pfx certificate and verify the token:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certpath, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var privateKey = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);

string payload = JWT.Decode(tokenString, privateKey);
```

Comment: In an asymmetric scenario, aren't JWTs signatures verified using the public key? I'm a little confused why the code sample is passing the privateKey to the Decode method?

Comment: I have the same question. the authentication server that generated JWT owns the private key. And this JWT will be used to call another application server, could public key be placed to application server and for verifying this JWT?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. The link and the code don't work.