# c# How to verify signature JWT?

Tags: c#, jwt, signature

I have a token, a file containing public key and I want to verify the signature.
I tried to verify signature based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055158/is-there-a-json-web-token-jwt-example-in-c).

However, decodedCrypto and decodedSignature don't match.

Here is my code:

```
public static string Decode(string token, string key, bool verify)
    {
        var parts = token.Split('.');
        var header = parts[0];
        var payload = parts[1];
        byte[] crypto = Base64UrlDecode(parts[2]);

        var headerJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(header));
        var headerData = JObject.Parse(headerJson);
        var payloadJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(payload));
        var payloadData = JObject.Parse(payloadJson);

        if (verify)
        {
            var bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(header, ".", payload));
            var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            var algorithm = (string)headerData["alg"];
            var signature = HashAlgorithms[GetHashAlgorithm(algorithm)](keyBytes, bytesToSign);
            var decodedCrypto = Convert.ToBase64String(crypto);
            var decodedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

            if (decodedCrypto != decodedSignature)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Invalid signature. Expected {0} got {1}", decodedCrypto, decodedSignature));
            }
        }

        return payloadData.ToString();
    }
```

I'm sure that the signature of token is valid. I try to verify on https://jwt.io/ and it showed that Signature verified.
So the problem is the algorithm to encode, decode.

Is there anyone can solve this problem? The algorithm is RS256

[image]

Comment: The simplest answer was reported in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055158/is-there-any-json-web-token-jwt-example-in-c by @Thomas.

Comment: @KarthickJayaraman I mention the reference above, but it doesn't work. Don't you look at the question carefully?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally got a solution from my colleague.

For those who have the same problem, try my code:

```
public static string Decode(string token, string key, bool verify = true)
{
    string[] parts = token.Split('.');
    string header = parts[0];
    string payload = parts[1];
    byte[] crypto = Base64UrlDecode(parts[2]);

    string headerJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(header));
    JObject headerData = JObject.Parse(headerJson);

    string payloadJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(payload));
    JObject payloadData = JObject.Parse(payloadJson);

    if (verify)
    {
        var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key); // your key here

        AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(keyBytes);
        RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
        RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

        SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
        byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parts[0] + '.' + parts[1]));

        RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
        rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        if (!rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, FromBase64Url(parts[2])))
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Invalid signature"));
    }

    return payloadData.ToString();
}
```

It works for me. The algorithm is RS256.

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks very much. watch out: RSACryptoServiceProvider and SHA256 are disposable

Comment: Is there a PS256 implementation similar to this RS256 one? Or do I have to change the hash algorithm to solve that? I do not wish to pass in the private key, only the public key as above

Comment: Man.. Java and Python have libraries which allow you to do this dynamically just by passing in the algorithm and public key. I am going crazy at the lack of a remotely close equivalent for .NET land...

Comment: What is "Base64UrlDecode"? I'm getting this error: The name 'Base64UrlDecode' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @NagarajAlagusudaram Did you add the reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urldecode?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ?

Answer (score 18):

How about using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`?
it could look something like this:

```
public bool ValidateToken(string token, byte[] secret)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(secret)
    };

    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    try
    {
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       return false;
    }

    return validatedToken != null;
}
```

Be aware I haven't tested it but we used a similar implementation in one of the projects

Comment: What is "BinarySecretSecurityToken" here? No reference here

Comment: @ANguyen: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.tokens.binarysecretsecuritytoken(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is part of `IdentityModel` library.

Comment: System.IdentityModel is part of .NET Framework and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt u can get via Nuget

Comment: You can use IssuerSgningKey with X509SecurityKey instead if you can transform the key to or already have a certificate.

Comment: What version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens is this? 5.2.1 does not have a IssuerSigningToken option and I'm also not seeing a BinarySecretSecurityToken.

Comment: Not clear to me too what BinarySecretSecurityToken is.

Comment: @theAdmiral https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.tokens.binarysecretsecuritytoken(v=vs.110).aspx and thanks for downvoting because something is not clear to you

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old thread but I could have `recommended` you to use **[this library](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt)** instead of writing on your own. It has got some good documentation to get started. Am using it without any issues.

Comment: This library RS256 implementation is still not functional because it expects a private key to verify the token signature

Answer (score 0):

`byte[] crypto = Base64UrlDecode(parts[2]);`

In this line you are base64 decoding signature part of `JWT` token, but as I know that part isn't base64 encoded. Please try this code. ( I have commented out unnecessary lines )

```
public static string Decode(string token, string key, bool verify)
{
    var parts = token.Split('.');
    var header = parts[0];
    var payload = parts[1];
    // byte[] crypto = Base64UrlDecode(parts[2]);
    var jwtSignature = parts[2];

    var headerJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(header));
    var headerData = JObject.Parse(headerJson);
    var payloadJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(payload));
    var payloadData = JObject.Parse(payloadJson);

    if (verify)
    {
        var bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(header, ".", payload));
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        var algorithm = (string)headerData["alg"];
        var computedJwtSignature = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(HashAlgorithms[GetHashAlgorithm(algorithm)](keyBytes, bytesToSign));
        // var decodedCrypto = Convert.ToBase64String(crypto);
        // var decodedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

        if (jwtSignature != computedJwtSignature)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Invalid signature. Expected {0} got {1}", decodedCrypto, decodedSignature));
        }
    }

    return payloadData.ToString();
}
```

Comment: computedJwtSignature returns "{�3�R4p/�����g�o����1�G��#�i"
And they dont match.
My algorithm is RS256

Comment: What does this line return? ( value and type please )
`HashAlgorithms[GetHashAlgorithm(algorithm)](keyBytes, bytesToSign)`

Comment: As I know RS256 should get both public and private keys for computing hash, but you are giving only one.

Comment: I just need a public key to verify. 
I tried on https://jwt.io/ and it returns signnature verified.

Comment: You put only public key in jwt.io website ? As I see the public/private keys are required there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107103/discussion-between-aram-kocharyan-and-a-nguyen).

Comment: @bot_insane public key, located here https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys consists of 2 parts, `n` and `e`. How does `key` parameter in your example is being constructed?