# Oauth2 authentication with Private Key C#

Tags: java, c#, rest, jwt, cryptography

I am attempting to authenticate via Oauth2 to an API however, I had trouble creating the request because of a private key. I was provided a sample code by the vendor which is Java and I converted it over to C# but I can't seem to get the private key into the JWT request.

Side note, the client, secret and URL's have been masked for this example.

**Working Java code**

```
public class Test {

    private static final String RSSO_URL = "https://test-dev.onbmc.com/rsso";

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "36fa1bd2-6f92-408e-b7e4-dd4df7a9cfaz";

    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjBgEAAoIBAQC169y6kMo/hZ/3oRFKwU1bxmzCJhWgH54j3Vn1JW4SmgO3rH5bHkVcqt03aaQmQms/fBDe2SlCKS3pxH6pVXB8aKQj8EOPWstwjvjsQrCiKLyqAMbc6E7IBVp1Dq77wFtv+P3fk80/9OA4a6ahr9Dp14+3YawyOU/5Ebf/i2WwKkySTgQOGLXvk3+LtsoODubMAnyJYWb6e+Uhrbn/vSqlGDDjGtANahw5oWjqFy8IYFttzMNB0VF2+sKIzGvQ+Izlo+u4wTgN7pB5g8bSz9Q92QzeWRVh7OCaef3L0i6Ozp3rO46bo3+G+QJdn4UKPcYMubtNGMC511aDU8Yay4IPAgMBAAECggEAMGTwMQk3ZDKN3XgRe4t0osdCNlufQRtoHC5UMeylHXmvJ3tRmbexx/cdqwgxTKQ6l4bPjhjC6wC9YASPlUhPRikoEQ9nSYljuSuveFo9VsXzel3+iOGbo4YZDC69yebf7CeWkZVl8m+X/ipVB4oXzz0y1Bu9jRbF+YIHKonQoU4MgsQQrYa8J8cSx75fkByNj9HdQtd99aK2jsMSArQ1R+PnUjDWpxlZBAowRmaw6iPWJbHmhLUSyrIvBJOo3fNZlXPS/S8jL5s0n137K640WFjy5LBakooHqmjfaFk/5z5krBaWaehDXU2AXLcKRQi946QhC99leSxBTastfjIh0QKBgQDZDZRME+GvJwnnMOht0BuVjcazCkY5LcfxD4vwQeK8p7zyqaxcvNu0+0ulKy+kqP6d/Q1ITIXlQDEA8a2d/iiOhSI84Y/g9az9ZSvRHH/Z5gRdRrymZJcqCzzpxjqi0uvaKOQUWwrKthnxnAS+1oJPlqOc1CtO/j4qzc7I2D7VxQKBgQDWkH5YTYLM5EWos1zdEmVqnIrUYbKlkyHJWSYnC/f5VsOoVEV4R1012w3HfwPceRjYOxeUtHTPN3MB9B5Xn5d3oBFBk8Md9phD5St9KXGakPY0sWC1yFEg8/Zr9fVm5jren6tJQmhKEeiV6DtueqQShEVVIEJixrQQkwFQ4SvJwwKBgCKh+Qyei38gEoNyGVQURaJ6Sb8dn5DWDjYXjfOa/6usdAigLCFr/P6Grk4/cs2qLV5WFz13AFJRCMCmz1YLTLtY4Nqn/wYdDSotb21hR8Ej44Rimg1OtZP+0QxYFdkPIJThu2rIEBPCNKeJhnRQ0+ARIDAQ5ownIxI/XoRLhNMlAoGAQl9mRgiMKrd+eOYrFtPm/Wi5ZWNncOKns/JY5AFGzyGw2rRe3QsuYUeG5qx61Eu9jL4S2FROQf+EGxmZ/T8ICuBAFkoQNIegqHgO0OPuGYM4NiqcoP77Ybc2BkWKiS81DMLVqI7bVfZePWkeYVmcwYGbNO8KuiV/dBUVdiCBfCMCgYEAoUvJefM+ENuhnxrH6A+4lEH4CI64gkQ5tkF3JeAMCiIov5OEuJx+65ULXeAwhrvcLB3Ginh0hI2RNQGV5iOeu0+sHmNA8yt0ivoCweNxiPM0RGWcH5FFBzI88WlGbMl0eg3NHt9jV5yTwNJYonjPFgCUkasaclhDZlZxgN891LA=";
   
    private static final String  PRIVATE_KEY = "MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDhY8LmtZ7fZOAX\n" +
"gw7SKyHzZ6Q0H0ss+3cJ7NEkEofUN2IfycE5u6eQb396uN16bzZaQcwnK9He3xwk\n" +
"3H4wWLzOUlhfuo87bJ34VdNBa1hfAk4iyk1ZgyufGy6MKgwycXhIl9wibX/f1fmF\n" +
"khHnkXVyYY5hSewceCT51bMzcv+psGf7KkN8jh/bRb+/GGfxVy13GKfFTzwY1Y7G\n" +
"SH7J00EaUQsEVCbkV3HK185v6t1fb2faao2imgj/Xqzc/DBbConBoF8/89SJSuf9\n" +
"1RVGdctNwqerMOUoDJ2ynHNqhbO3POq6O1XMi0c75q4xdtrNWLa8A5ONPUXDgIo/\n" +
"Ddwj1tTNAgMBAAECggEACG83yXNtfRWkzyxv3wyPKjEsM2kiYo4Mf9oVX4C0BYyH\n" +
"BwKBURxFIoIRprGJVD4aLhl9PtAEfA8kWfrIXB3N/viU5wwvtP0VEkh/7dhLB88p\n" +
"xmKEr39ZoAwf203tg+u8IRdRvRYU7Xbv7gAv3FcUqpGdBuYByHT0iUbmfFvm1l46\n" +
"HD2ypQFKr3a536w2sFR6XKK6G+Al69lyg0Hg4jXmmDMo+xoxqrJeYxT11G6iBWmy\n" +
"UXKDdOVx4BarT+dcnCUP0yahmQz08XObNDNphWG/aOFF6cMyU4hNkK9q0AC6sAzQ\n" +
"89dTVTPErjEJcJZ16mtI9nv5u4VKfbL1mU+ivb4pQQKBgQD+FdFx+BKojVYilT1i\n" +
"WMbXabRtm03NezgzSgIDKTxiewoQAy+n+InGPy2pz18/1DP8kasnsU8VZvRM7dXV\n" +
"lJTXrqOM/lMN8vMt7/fpz0PYEDP6Qz7CLxA0xEcW2qFR4RAQzq3xXIH/7M4VUZzD\n" +
"qzznD8aJaG5fsSExt7aITU984QKBgQDjFpVsxDxF3YZBhonuNaSrvTdDwbMqdCLT\n" +
"ZoXUL+4aKY78cD2FCfdqJ5O1uyrAqgCgjouiVnNRzDy3qSSGxaiwpI3+FA8cCNiS\n" +
"W0CE/urjDDeXU0Q5jDSBdljBF23wf9mNmXpgXSHfgQVTIiVMVD5tNhU/ORu5PXzo\n" +
"SdW67DLJbQKBgDYYbRQnrclG9hy8y2nh3svEDI70bq4d2tRIoG8N23ZYHcdU9lN7\n" +
"vdGAZ/dsWCodwse2N8tmm6DB36d1R36GeL4Gx3lgOEyS+iVAnvafkyEwKfDRWk47\n" +
"eObTFxONjqUBFsuNRUlK2b6kKygszQR3s6q6GBnvKviinJ+aLnmMhCzhAoGBAKLC\n" +
"gP6f87/kcmFsiFePYyMkTwPlRQDclEloZesbH1DpEG6mE7HS3t3a1+ec6puEPUbW\n" +
"ZAZKaATsmWgZdvCRosJYbtz4i4vQW0kq1id8feWV1BJJv9BvSQKxTBO5Mzb4q3jt\n" +
"0+RVW/3Rf3uCMbFvf/7OkJPr3o76HxhuMx3yRMRRAoGAZiFbVjd3EKUdyE0O3QSh\n" +
"46KzTdT0ENhBlN2dpCdJjHJm3Lcxa7uY4sxa8NqYUW0NO2qRSd42IKfGX3qqi7wf\n" +
"+rUFFixCzQOoucR/ekTw+542Nbc0QejAQ0SUDwgHWX8L8Yi+W3UsBL2YLLIw5ged\n" +
"7Ghsl3cgdKPMlAh1kzxsWic=";
   

    public static JsonPath getOAuthToken() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        return with().log().all()
                
                
                .contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
                .formParam("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")
               
                .formParam("assertion", getClientJwt())
                
                .formParam("client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer")
             
                .formParam("redirect_uri", "https://test-dev-restapi.us.onbmc.com/api/jwt/login")
                .formParam("audience", "test-dev-restapi.us.onbmc.com")
                .formParam("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
                .formParam("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
                .when()
                .post(RSSO_URL + "/oauth2/token")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                .extract()
                .response()
                .getBody()
                .jsonPath();
    }
   
   static String getClientJwt() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(loadPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY))
                .setIssuer(CLIENT_ID)
                .setSubject("JWT")
                .setAudience("test-dev-restapi.us.onbmc.com")
                .setExpiration(calendar.getTime())
                .compact();
    }

    static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String privateKeyStr) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKeyStr));
            
       
       return kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
    }

    //@Test
    public void getOauthAccessTokenUsingJwtGrantType() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Trying to get OAuth Access and Refresh tokens");
        JsonPath response = getOAuthToken();
        System.out.println("Access Token = " + response.getString("access_token"));
        System.out.println("Refresh Token = " + response.getString("refresh_token"));
        System.out.println("Expires in = " + response.getString("expires_in"));
        System.out.println("OAuth2 Token was successfully obtained.");
    }

    public static void main(String str[]) throws Exception {
        JsonPath response = getOAuthToken();
        
    }
    
    }
```

**Converted Java code to C#**

```
using java.security;
using java.security.spec;
using JWT;
using JWT.Algorithms;
using JWT.Builder;
using JWT.Serializers;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using System;
using System.Buffers.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {

private static string RSSO_URL = "https://test-dev.onbmc.com/rsso";

`enter code here`private static string CLIENT_ID = "36fa1bd2-6f92-408e-b7e4-dd4df7a9cfaz";

    private static string CLIENT_SECRET = "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";
   
    private static string  PRIVATE_KEY = "MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDhY8LmtZ7fZOAX\n" +
"gw7SKyHzZ6Q0H0ss+3cJ7NEkEofUN2IfycE5u6eQb396uN16bzZaQcwnK9He3xwk\n" +
"3H4wWLzOUlhfuo87bJ34VdNBa1hfAk4iyk1ZgyufGy6MKgwycXhIl9wibX/f1fmF\n" +
"khHnkXVyYY5hSewceCT51bMzcv+psGf7KkN8jh/bRb+/GGfxVy13GKfFTzwY1Y7G\n" +
"SH7J00EaUQsEVCbkV3HK185v6t1fb2faao2imgj/Xqzc/DBbConBoF8/89SJSuf9\n" +
"1RVGdctNwqerMOUoDJ2ynHNqhbO3POq6O1XMi0c75q4xdtrNWLa8A5ONPUXDgIo/\n" +
"Ddwj1tTNAgMBAAECggEACG83yXNtfRWkzyxv3wyPKjEsM2kiYo4Mf9oVX4C0BYyH\n" +
"BwKBURxFIoIRprGJVD4aLhl9PtAEfA8kWfrIXB3N/viU5wwvtP0VEkh/7dhLB88p\n" +
"xmKEr39ZoAwf203tg+u8IRdRvRYU7Xbv7gAv3FcUqpGdBuYByHT0iUbmfFvm1l46\n" +
"HD2ypQFKr3a536w2sFR6XKK6G+Al69lyg0Hg4jXmmDMo+xoxqrJeYxT11G6iBWmy\n" +
"UXKDdOVx4BarT+dcnCUP0yahmQz08XObNDNphWG/aOFF6cMyU4hNkK9q0AC6sAzQ\n" +
"89dTVTPErjEJcJZ16mtI9nv5u4VKfbL1mU+ivb4pQQKBgQD+FdFx+BKojVYilT1i\n" +
"WMbXabRtm03NezgzSgIDKTxiewoQAy+n+InGPy2pz18/1DP8kasnsU8VZvRM7dXV\n" +
"lJTXrqOM/lMN8vMt7/fpz0PYEDP6Qz7CLxA0xEcW2qFR4RAQzq3xXIH/7M4VUZzD\n" +
"qzznD8aJaG5fsSExt7aITU984QKBgQDjFpVsxDxF3YZBhonuNaSrvTdDwbMqdCLT\n" +
"ZoXUL+4aKY78cD2FCfdqJ5O1uyrAqgCgjouiVnNRzDy3qSSGxaiwpI3+FA8cCNiS\n" +
"W0CE/urjDDeXU0Q5jDSBdljBF23wf9mNmXpgXSHfgQVTIiVMVD5tNhU/ORu5PXzo\n" +
"SdW67DLJbQKBgDYYbRQnrclG9hy8y2nh3svEDI70bq4d2tRIoG8N23ZYHcdU9lN7\n" +
"vdGAZ/dsWCodwse2N8tmm6DB36d1R36GeL4Gx3lgOEyS+iVAnvafkyEwKfDRWk47\n" +
"eObTFxONjqUBFsuNRUlK2b6kKygszQR3s6q6GBnvKviinJ+aLnmMhCzhAoGBAKLC\n" +
"gP6f87/kcmFsiFePYyMkTwPlRQDclEloZesbH1DpEG6mE7HS3t3a1+ec6puEPUbW\n" +
"ZAZKaATsmWgZdvCRosJYbtz4i4vQW0kq1id8feWV1BJJv9BvSQKxTBO5Mzb4q3jt\n" +
"0+RVW/3Rf3uCMbFvf/7OkJPr3o76HxhuMx3yRMRRAoGAZiFbVjd3EKUdyE0O3QSh\n" +
"46KzTdT0ENhBlN2dpCdJjHJm3Lcxa7uY4sxa8NqYUW0NO2qRSd42IKfGX3qqi7wf\n" +
"+rUFFixCzQOoucR/ekTw+542Nbc0QejAQ0SUDwgHWX8L8Yi+W3UsBL2YLLIw5ged\n" +
"7Ghsl3cgdKPMlAh1kzxsWic=";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            
            //create RestSharp client and POST request object
            var client = new RestClient(RSSO_URL + "/oauth2/token");
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Method = Method.Post;

            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
            request.AddParameter("client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer");
            request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://test-dev-restapi.us.onbmc.com/api/jwt/login");
            request.AddParameter("audience", "test-dev-restapi.us.onbmc.com");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);
            request.AddParameter("assertion", Program.getClientJwt());
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            //return an AccessToken
            var poo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        
    }

    public static string getClientJwt()  {

        DateTime exp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);
        
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PRIVATE_KEY));
        var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);


        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(CLIENT_ID, "miamidade-dev-restapi.us.onbmc.com", null, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1), signIn);
        
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
          
    }



    public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String privateKeyStr)
    {
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyStr);
        

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedBytes);
        return kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
    }

}
 }
```

When I send the request, I get the error
{"error_description":"Not valid request, JWT is rejected","error":"invalid_grant"}

Comment: perhaps the `assertion` provided with a different hashing algorithm. ensure that you're using the correct algorithm, for the `assertion`.

Comment: although, this post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055158/is-there-any-json-web-token-jwt-example-in-c

Comment: I confirmed with the vendor that the hashing algorithm is RS256.

Comment: the private key is base64 encoded, perhaps you need to use `Convert.FromBase64` to get its bytes. also you can debug the key from https://jwt.io